# XPROC - Generation of files in secondary port

Tags: xproc

My requirement is to generate one XML file and few HTML files in the secondary port. I have configured few steps in XProc.

Here’s the sample code:

```
<p:xslt name="create-document">
    <p:input port="stylesheet">
      <p:document href="stylesheet.xsl" />
    </p:input>  
  </p:xslt>  
  <p:for-each>
    <p:iteration-source>
      <p:pipe step="create-document" port="secondary" />
    </p:iteration-source>
   <p:store>
    <p:with-option name="doctype-public" select="'-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN'" />
    <p:with-option name="doctype-system" select="'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-frameset.dtd'" />
    <p:with-option name="encoding" select="'UTF-8'" />
    <p:with-option name="media-type" select="'text/html'" />
    <p:with-option name="method" select="'xhtml'" />
    <p:with-option name="omit-xml-declaration" select="'no'" />
  </p:store>
  </p:for-each>
```

The problem here is HTML file is generated properly. And the XML file is generated, but I am not able to view the XML content. Instead it displays everything in HTML format.This is because of `<p:store>` in the above code snippet.

How do you have two `<p:store>` steps? (One for HTML and the other for XML)

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice if you could somehow determine with which `xsl:result-document` parameters each document on the secondary output was written. You would be able to duplicate those for your `p:store`. But you can derive other things from each document. You can retrieve the document name using `base-uri()`, and you can look at for instance the root element. You can put these values in a variable using:

```
<p:variable name="path" select="base-uri(/*)"/>
<p:variable name="root" select="local-name(/*)"/>
```

(Put these just below the `p:iteration-source`.)

You then need to decide how to call `p:store`. You could use XPath if, provided your XProc parser supports XPath 2.0 (like XMLCalabash does). But I’d recommend using a `p:choose` like this:

```
<p:choose>
    <p:when test="ends-with($path, '.xhtml')">
        <p:store
            doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN"
            doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-frameset.dtd"
            encoding="UTF-8"
            media-type="text/html"
            method="xhtml"
            omit-xml-declaration="no">
            <p:with-option name="href" select="$path"/>
        </p:store>
    </p:when>
    <p:otherwise>
        <p:store
            encoding="UTF-8"
            media-type="application/xml"
            method="xml"
            omit-xml-declaration="no">
            <p:with-option name="href" select="$path"/>
        </p:store>
    </p:otherwise>
</p:choose>
```

(This entire `p:choose` replaces the `p:store` you already have.)

The test in `p:when` only looks at `$path`, but you could include a test for `$root` as well, if you like.

It also requires you to use `.xhtml` as extension in your `xsl:result-document` statements for the HTML output, but you can easily tweak that if you like.

The `var` and the `choose` should be enough to get your XML written properly, at least.

Good luck!